# Catch values correctly in RxJS TypeScript (Angular 2)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I'm learning Angular2, coming from years of development in Angular 1.x. I've run into some issues with [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS), and particularly how to catch and handle errors. In my example I'm trying to authenticate a user, by passing a Facebook access token to our own API. This works great when it works, but I can't seem to get the error handling to work the way I expect it to.

The method call hierarchy is as follows

```
SignInComponent.facebookLoginResponse
    => AuthService.facebookLogin
        => APIService.Post
```

When the server returns an error (status code 4xx), I expect the client to map the error and catch it in my SignInComponent error handling block. Instead the console shows me the following errors (the `ErrorHandler.handle` is never called):

```
-> EXCEPTION: [object Object]                core.umd.js:3488
-> Uncaught > Object {errors: Array[1]}      Subscribe.ts:241
```

Below are the relevant snippets of code

```
export class SignInComponent{
    ...
    public facebookLoginResponse(response : FB.LoginStatusResponse){
        if (response.status == "connected"){
            let observable = this.auth.facebookLogin(response.authResponse.accessToken);

            observable.subscribe(() => {
                this.router.navigate(['influencer']);
            }, (error : ErrorResponse) => {
                ErrorHandler.handle(error, "Couldn't log in due to the following reasons:");
            });
        }
    }
    ...
}

export class Auth{
    ...
    facebookLogin(accessToken : String) : Observable<AuthResponse>{
        let observable = this.api.Post<AuthResponse>("influencer/auth/facebook", {
            token: accessToken
        });

        observable.subscribe((response : AuthResponse) => {
            Auth.handleAuthSuccess(response, SessionType.Influencer);
        });

        return observable;
    }
    ...
}

export class API{
    ...
    public Post<T>(path : String, postData) : Observable<T>{
        return this.http.post(this.basePath + path, postData)
            .map((response : Response) => {
                return API.extractData<T>(response);
            })
            .catch(API.handleError)
            .share();
    }

    private static extractData<T>(response : Response) : T{
        return <T>response.json();
    }

    private static handleError (error: Response) {
        let errorResponse : ErrorResponse;
        ...
        return Observable.throw(errorResponse);
    }
    ...
}
```

It seems like the `share` call in `API.Post` breaks the error handling. However without it, the request is sent as many times as we have subscribed to the observable (in this case, two times). How should I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if the following applies to your case, but in most cases "splitting up" a stream into multiple subscriptions is not necessary when writing processes sequential(which should be no problem in most cases, since there is onyl 1 thread anyways), in your case try to remove the `share()` and use the following:

```
export class Auth {
    ...
    facebookLogin(accessToken : String) : Observable<AuthResponse>{
        return this.api.Post<AuthResponse>("influencer/auth/facebook", {
            token: accessToken
        })
        .do((response : AuthResponse) => Auth.handleAuthSuccess(response, SessionType.Influencer));
    }
    ...
}
```